# I'm trying to create slices on a 3d plot at specific points

Tags: python, plotly

Let's say I want to plot the slices at the following points: (1,0,0) (2,2,2) (-1,2,0) (1,2,1)
i'm using Jupyter notebook and python

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see how to post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: [matplotlib 3D scatterplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html)